# Python. Модуль rpyc. Сохранение переменной после закрытия соединения

Tags: python, python-3.x

Тут скорее общий вопрос к хранению переменных в python. Есть локальный сервер на rpyc, подключаюсь к нему, сохраняю данные в стек, если закрываю соединение, данные из стека исчезают(weakly-referenced object no longer exists).

Общая структура такова.

Есть файл локального сервера на rpyc, который выполняет вызов данных из некоторого класса при помощи rpyc.Service.

```
class MyService(rpyc.Service): 
    def exposed_get_global(self):
        """
        обращение к статическому методу класса
        FunctionGetter для вызова глобальной структуры
        """
        return FunctionGetter.print_global_structure() #print_global_structure - возвращает значение словаря с данными

    def exposed_setVbase(self):
        pass


from rpyc.utils.server import ThreadedServer
from threading import Thread

server = ThreadedServer(MyService, port = 12333)
t = Thread(target = server.start)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

Есть получение данных из файла-клиента

```
import rpyc
data_stack = []

conn = rpyc.connect("localhost", 12333) #подключаюсь к локальному серверу
x = conn.root.get_global() #вызов
data_stack.append(x) #добавляю данные
conn.close() #закрываю соединение(в этом есть необходимость)
```

При попытке получения доступа к стеку данных, после закрытия соединения, получаю ошибку, **weakly-referenced object no longer exists**
Я понимаю, что закрытие соединения приводит к тому, что данные в стеке(data_stack) становятся более недоступны. И не помню, как сделать так, чтобы эти данные сохранялись.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причину я так и не нашёл, поэтому, как вариант, использовал "топорный" метод обхода проблемы, с помощью модуля pickle. НО, как оказалось, для его работы с rpyc, нужно разрешить в настройках rpyc передачу данных в pickle(подробнее здесь - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27139341/7646284)

В итоге, локальный сервер:

```
import rpyc 
rpyc.core.protocol.DEFAULT_CONFIG['allow_pickle'] = True #разрешить pickle в rpyc

class MyService(rpyc.Service): 
        def exposed_get_global(self):
            """
            обращение к статическому методу класса
            FunctionGetter для вызова глобальной структуры
            """
            return FunctionGetter.print_global_structure() #print_global_structure - возвращает значение словаря с данными

        def exposed_setVbase(self):
            pass


from rpyc.utils.server import ThreadedServer
from threading import Thread

server = ThreadedServer(MyService, port = 12333,protocol_config = rpyc.core.protocol.DEFAULT_CONFIG)
t = Thread(target = server.start)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

Файл-клиент:

```
import rpyc
import pickle

def save_data(self, value):
    with open('data.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(value, f)

conn = rpyc.connect("localhost", 12333) #подключаюсь к локальному серверу
x = conn.root.get_global() #вызов
save_data(x) #сохранение
conn.close() #закрываю соединение(в этом есть необходимость)
```